# How to VLOOKUP the second column from an IMPORTHTML result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, importrange

I am hopeful this simple question has a simple answer.

I am using the `IMPORTHTML` function to import a table to my spreadsheet. I want to find a particular result from that imported table.

However, is entering this function in A1

```
=VLOOKUP("findthis",IMPORTHTML("https://exampletable.com","table",1),3,0)
```

the `VLOOKUP` only search for `findthis` in column A, but I need to search column B.

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple, duplicate your `IMPORTHTML` and construct a VR array like:

```
=VLOOKUP("findthis", {
 QUERY(IMPORTHTML("https://exampletable.com", "table", 1), "select Col2", 0), 
       IMPORTHTML("https://exampletable.com", "table", 1)}, 4, 0)
```